# How to display Parabolic Motion and how to find Final Position of a Sprite in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to move a sprite with swipe gesture, with any angle and any speed depends upon the swipes from the user and  it end with trajectory.  According with the swipe angle and power, how find the final position at where sprite reaches? and how display parabolic movement?

Please check this image for more clarification [image]

Answer (score 3):

My answer to same question  :)

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/220434

For trajectory tracking and Position prediction check the following links

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10862

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15007